# Is there a word to describe names that have no meaning but take on meaning over time for example "Google"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes we create names for things that are just meaningless identifiers, the only example that springs to mind is "Google". That "Google" originally had no meaning may be disputed but this is besides the point. We do create nonsense words to name things, usually to ensure that the name is original and unique however over time these words aquire meaning; Google is no longer a nonsense word and is regularly used as a verb.

Is there a word to describe these sorts of words?

"Google" is a search engine, but I am not familiar with its use as a proprietory eponym, for example "Bing is a type of Google" does not sound correct (to me), I do not use the word Google to mean search engine. My experience of the word Google is normally as a verb i.e. "to google something".

Comment: You mean '[coining](https://www.lexico.com/definition/coin#:~:text=Invent%20(a%20new%20word%20or%20phrase))'?

Comment: They are neologisms! https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/neologism

Comment: @user121863 your comment is an answer, not merely a comment.

Comment: @Anton - I’m pretty sure it is a duplicate. The question has been asked before.

Comment: Oh, and there I was thinking you were “spot on”. Sometimes it is just easier to answer a question rather than spend ages looking to see if is was answered somewhere else in the tens of thousands of questions. Lazy of me.

Comment: @user121863 neologisms! Thanks - I'll accept this as the answer if you wish to submit it. I did try to find a duplicate but nothing seemed to answer my question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a designer's name or brand name as a substitute for the product itself](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/458430/using-a-designers-name-or-brand-name-as-a-substitute-for-the-product-itself)

Comment: A brand name used as a generic term is not a neologism - that is a fabricated word or phrase (although the brand name was itself fabricated). It is a **proprietory eponym**.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks, if I'm understanding the meaning of proprietory eponym then this would mean that "Google" means "search engine" in the same way that Frisbee means "flying disc", which I do not feel it does, although this is obviously a matter of opinion. I've tried to imporve my question to highlight this.

Comment: One difference between **frisbee** and **google** is that one is a noun and the other is a verb and one would not say "Bing is a type of Google." So I am still not clear whether the question refers to the original naming of Google Inc or to the generic verb which it has become. Aside: a **hoover** is an eponym because it was named it after Hoover who manufactured it.

Comment: @Weather Vane I believe 'neologism' covers novel usages as well as newly accepted words. It's a broad hypernym here, with 'metonymy' and 'semantic shift' also ballpark.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth AFAIK Larry Page and Sergey Brin didn't know how to spell **googol** so it was an accidental neologism ;)

Comment: When a function word converts to a lexical item (eg 'up' converting from preposition to verb in 'up the ante') the term used is _degrammaticalisation_. However, _google_ (V) has arisen from a [mis]naming followed by intercategorial conversion from (albeit pretty arbitrary) noun to verb.

Comment: **Every** meaningful word is a something that originally had no meaning and then acquired it over time.

Comment: Uh, "google" derives from "googol".